# How to properly design interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I have two classes. Let's call them `PostClass` and `CommentClass`. Both classes implement the `Reportable` interface:

```
public interface Reportable {

    void report();

    boolean isReported();

    . . .
```

Now I need to add two additional methods to each one of the classes. These methods logically fit into the same interface but needs to have different names. For example:

`PostClass`    will have methods -> `remove()`, `restore()`

`CommentClass` will have methods -> `hide()`, `show()`

**Question**: What would be the preferred way to design this change? The options are as I see it:

1. Create an additional interface which will extend the `Reportable` interface.  *Problem: Too many interfaces*
2. Add all four new methods into the `Reportable` interface and then just leave the irrelevant two methods unimplemented in each class. *Problem: Untidy/ugly*

Comment: I would find good naming for methods so that it can be used for both Post and Comment. So that I can only have that two methods in my interface.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev These methods describe actual existing application logic and I need these methods reflect that so it will make sense to me and others.

Comment: How do these two (four?) methods "logically fit into the same interface" if they are irrelevant to one or the other implementing class? Seems like a contradiction. Each method in `Reportable` either logically applies to all `Reportable` objects or the method doesn't belong in `Reportable`.

Comment: @TedHopp Each one of these classes can be reported. Once it has been reported you can either `remove` or `restore` it in one case and `hide` or `show` in another. The intention here was to keep the names to better reflect the business logic.

Comment: Yes, I get that the two classes have some behavior in common that's captured by the `Reportable` interface. However, each class also has behavior unique to that class, so I fail to see how those class-specific behaviors "logically fit" into the same interface. They aren't behaviors in common and don't belong in the same interface. (Unless at some level you think of `remove` and `hide` as somehow equivalent and likewise with `restore` and `show`. But then, why do they "need" different names?)

Comment: @TedHopp Perhaps my understanding is wrong but when I say logically fit it's because I these are 2 actions that can be made on these classes as response to being reported. Maybe it will make more sense if I add that I am working on automated tests of a webapp so there are actual visual objects that correspond to my classes. The names need to be different to emphasize the business logic and since the implementation of each one of these methods is slightly different as well. Hope that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: @EugeneS wht is the difference between hide() & remove() also between show() & restore() ?? are they different in purpose/business logic??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Perhaps it will make more sense if I say that what I do here is test automation and I am trying to properly describe existing business elements in an existing app. While both classes I described share  a lot, their implementations are slightly different. For example, one of the differences is the names (hide/show...) that are actually buttons in the application. I wish to preserve the names of the actual buttons as that's the best way to keep code clear and to reflect the existing environment. Hope that helps.

Comment: @EugeneS so it is ok if I just assume they are different right? :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about having a few more interfaces, as long as their use and purpose is clear. These 2 options are valid:

1. `PostClass` implements `RemovableReportable`, which extends `Reportable`; And
   `CommentClass` implements `HideableReportable`, which extends `Reportable`.
2. `PostClass` implements both `Reportable` and `Removable`; And
   `CommentClass` implements both `Reportable` and `Hideable`.

But adding all four new methods into the `Reportable` interface and leaving two methods unimplemented in each class is **very** wrong, since it does not lead to code which is clean and easy to understand and use. The developer would have to learn which method to use in each case, thus making your code more difficult to use and modify. And what happens if some developer calls the wrong method? If the wrong method does nothing, bugs may go unnoticed. If it throws an exception, this will only catch bugs at runtime. And if it calls the other method then you have two ways of doing the same thing, which is also bad and confusing.

Unused methods in an interface are a code smell, and may indicate a design flaw.

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of implementing multiple interfaces. This might work for me, I will give that a go.

Answer (score 2):

If they do the same thing, then make up names that encompass the function; although that doesn't sound like what you want given the existing names.

Option 3: Create two new interfaces, `Removable` and `Hideable` and have each class implement the appropriate interface(s).

On second thought, I would probably recommend using `hide()` and `show()` since that seems to capture what's happening best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I considered that however I'd like to keep the methods names different to better reflect the actual business logic. The implementation is going to be slightly different as well.

Answer (score 0):

While the question would likely be classified as opinion based, my approach would be to still add two methods (`show()`,`hide()`) to the interface and have the classes implement it.

Below are few other options :

If you are using JDK8 you can try adding the above two methods as [default-methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in the interface so that it does not immediately break the existing implementation.

Also, apparently its possible to invoke the abstract method from a default method in the interface so it would technically be possible to have two generically named abstract methods and two (or four more) that are specifically named default methods but that would be overkill and would only add to the confusion.

You could consider having a total of six new methods. `show` and `hide` being abstract and also `showPost`/`hidePost` and `showComment` and `hideComment` being default classes which in turn invoke the abstract `show` and `hide` respectively. That way even if some implementation class calls the wrong alias by mistake it would still invoke the correct implementation (in theory).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I am going to describe in this answer is purely my opinion and subjective.

The following **points** must be kept in mind when designing this:

1. Any method added to Reportable (or in general any supertype) should be applicable to all subtypes regardless.
2. A method should describe a behaviour of the class, something that the class is capable of 'doing'.

> Point 2 explanation

Think of the method `postClass.remove()`, which can be read as 'A `PostClass` knows how to remove...'. But remove what? Itself? From where?

For me, 'removing' and 'restoring/adding' seems like something that can be done on a `Collection` of `PostClass` or `CommentClass` by and not something that these classes do themselves. If I guess correctly, this is indeed how you must be using `PostClass` and `CommentClass` in your application (i.e. as a `Collection` of some sort). Now, a `PostClass` or `CommentClass` can get a callback `onRemove()`, `onRestore()`, `onHide()` or `onShow()` to do what's necessary for each of this actions when being removed/restored/hidden/shown.

The **advantage** of callbacks is that a class can choose to call `super` if they don't intend to do something special during the action.

> Design 1 - Reportable has the behaviour of being hidden,shown,restored and removed

So, for all 'reports' of your application, you can add these callbacks to the `Reportable` interface itself.

```
public interface Reportable {
    void report();
    boolean isReported();        
    void onRestore();
    void onRemove();
    void onHide();
    void onShow();
}
```

Usage could be something like this

```
public class User {
    private List<Reportable> reports;
    //... more User related code

   public void deleteReport(Reportable report) {
       //give report a chance to cleanup
       report.onDelete();
       //delete from user's list of reports
       this.reports.remove(report);
       //more code
   }
```

> Design 2 - Having separate interfaces

```
public interface Viewable {
    void onHide();
    void onShow();
}

public interface Disposable {
    void onRemove();
    void onRestore();
}

public class PostClass implements Reportable, Disposable {

}

public class CommentClass implements Reportable, Viewable {

}
```

Usage for this is pretty self explanatory I guess.

I prefer **Design 2** as it seems more clean and adheres to '**SOLID**' design principles.

Hope this helps.